# Is there a c# equivalent of m_nCmdShow?

Tags: c#

In an MFC program, you can determine whether the application shortcut had the Run value set to "Minimized" by checking the value of `m_nCmdShow`. Is there an equivalent way to do this in c#?

To clarify, I don't want to set the state of a particular form. If you look at the properties for a shortcut, there is a "Run" option. You can set this value to Normal Window, Minimized, or Maximized.

In C++ you can read what that startup value was set to by looking at `m_nCmdShow`. I need to do the same thing in C#.

**Update**

This attempt:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo;
    MessageBox.Show(processInfo.WindowStyle.ToString());
    ...
}
```

always reports `Normal`, no matter what the shortcut is set to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WindowsForms its the WindowState property of Form class. check it up in properties at design time or set it from code.

**Edit:** When running the program from a shortcut Windows is likely to use the CreateProcess API passing a STARTUPINFO structure to it.

from your Windows Forms application you get such structure in this way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo
```

which contains the property: `WindowStyle` and the available values for it are those of the enum:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle
```

so:

```
Hidden;
Minimized;
Maximized;
Normal;
```

and that's the mapping to `m_nCmdShow` the OP is looking for.

Comment: Interesting! how is that member set in MFC? its value must get assigned somewhere...

Comment: @Ifalin: see my last edit :) hope this answers completely your question.

Comment: strange... there was actually also another question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026395/how-to-pass-windowstate-from-desktop-shortcut-into-wpf-app

Comment: Maybe it makes a difference if your startup object is set to a form or a not. Mine is set to a class rather than a form, because there are some other things that need to happen on startup.

Answer (score 0):

This lets you retrieve the initial window state by accessing `NativeMethods.StartupInfo.GetInitialWindowStyle()` in your code. You can use more information by accessing `NativeMethods.StartupInfo.FromCurrentProcess`. If you start your program from cmd.exe with `START "My Program Title" /MIN MyProgram.exe`, you'll find "My Program Title" in `NativeMethods.StartupInfo.FromCurrentProcess.lpTitle` and `NativeMethods.StartupInfo.GetInitialWindowStyle()` returns `ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized`.

```
static partial class NativeMethods
{
    public static class StartupInfo
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class STARTUPINFO
        {
            public readonly UInt32 cb;  
            private IntPtr lpReserved;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public readonly string lpDesktop;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public readonly string lpTitle;
            public readonly UInt32 dwX;
            public readonly UInt32 dwY;
            public readonly UInt32 dwXSize;
            public readonly UInt32 dwYSize;
            public readonly UInt32 dwXCountChars;
            public readonly UInt32 dwYCountChars;
            public readonly UInt32 dwFillAttribute;
            public readonly UInt32 dwFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public readonly UInt16 wShowWindow;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] private UInt16 cbReserved2;
            private IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public readonly IntPtr hStdInput;
            public readonly IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public readonly IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        public readonly static STARTUPINFO FromCurrentProcess = null;

        const uint STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
        const ushort SW_HIDE = 0;
        const ushort SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        const ushort SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        const ushort SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        const ushort SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
        const ushort SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;
        const ushort SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern void GetStartupInfoW(IntPtr startupInfoPtr);

        static StartupInfo() //Static constructor
        {
            FromCurrentProcess = new STARTUPINFO();
            int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STARTUPINFO));
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(FromCurrentProcess, ptr, false);

            GetStartupInfoW(ptr);

            Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, FromCurrentProcess);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }

        public static ProcessWindowStyle GetInitialWindowStyle()
        {
            if ((FromCurrentProcess.dwFlags & STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW) == 0) return ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            switch (FromCurrentProcess.wShowWindow)
            {
                case SW_HIDE: return ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                case SW_SHOWNORMAL: return ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                case SW_MINIMIZE:
                case SW_FORCEMINIMIZE:
                case SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE:
                case SW_SHOWMINIMIZED: return ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                case SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED: return ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                default: return ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```